# ToolTip still visible even if form is minimized or in background

Tags: c#, tooltip, foreground

In a WinForms Form I show a tooltip if a certain action has finished. I show it this way:

```
this.myToolTip.Show(message, this, location, duration);
```

The problem now is that the tooltip is still visible even if the form is going to be minimized or another form (different application) becomes active. Is there any solution for this problem?

Comment: Do it happens every time, or it is not to often?

Comment: Always! The window is minimized except of the tooltip. So the tooltip is visible over another application, if more than one application is opened.

Comment: There's no hope to guess at this from a single line of code.  A proper SSCCE is required to get help.

Comment: SSCCE (a new wtfword for me) would be nice indeed =D

Answer (score 0):

You may try to `.Hide` the tooltip when the form loses focus (deactivate). Like this:

```
    private void Form1_Deactivate(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.myToolTip.Hide(myTargetControl);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you show `Tooltip` manually, then you have to hide it manually as well. The only question is by which event you show it (because perhaps you want to re-show it). Typically all *event* tooltips are shown for tray icons, for this there is a dedicated component - [NotifyIcon](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.windows.forms.notifyicon%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), which comes with tooltip.

Otherwise, you are more likely showing tooltip when mouseovering something (`OnMouseEnter`, or better `OnMouseHover`), then just hide it in the `OnMouseLeave`.